# Show div if label = empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a label which displays an IP address:

```
<label id="internet_ipaddr" class="label_s1"></label>
```

What I want to do is display a div, `#youareoffline` if the label is empty. This was suggested as an implementation but after playing around I can't get it to work:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(#internet_ipaddr)) {
  $(#youareoffline).show();
}
```

Comment: There is a typo on the parameter I am not sure if thats the error IsNullOrWhiteSpace(#intenet_ipaddr) and your html: id="internet_ipaddr"

Comment: Thanks, Didn't notice that one, but unfortunately didn't fix it.

Comment: where's the `c#` tag ? many people are lost here

Answer (score 5):

The code you've attempted to use looks like a mix of C# (`string.isNullOrWhiteSpace()`) and pseudo code, not valid JS.

To make this work you can check if the element has any children (text nodes or otherwise) using the `is(':empty')` method, then show the relevant element. Try this:

```js
if ($('#internet_ipaddr').is(':empty')) {
  $('#youareoffline').show();
}
```

```css
#youareoffline { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label id="internet_ipaddr" class="label_s1"></label>
<div id="youareoffline">You are offline</div>
```

Also note that you can make the JS more succinct, although arguably harder to read, by using `toggle()`:

```
$('#youareoffline').toggle($('#internet_ipaddr').is(':empty'));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can easily do this using jQuery.

> HTML

```
<label id="label1"></label>
<div id="div1" style="display: none; color: red;">You are off line.</div>
```

> jQuery

```
  var labelText = $("#label1").text();
        if (!labelText) {
            $("#div1").show();
        }
```